# Matching Node.js aes-128-ecb (hex) encryption with C# .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, aes, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using an external API which expect the request body encrypted with aes-128-ecb (hex). I got it to work with JavaScript using Node.js with the following code (same key is used per session, but that's not the problem here):

```
    var crypto = require('crypto'),
        algorithm = 'aes-128-ecb',
        key = 'E572F45E8D79CAF92B4BD3B375820831';

    var fetchlist = {
        fetch_list: '[{"name":"itemInfo","controller":"catalog.BLCCatalogItem","method":"getDetailWithColor","params":[264,86]}]',
    };
    var message = JSON.stringify(fetchlist);

    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, key);
    var crypted = cipher.update(message, 'utf8', 'hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
```

I want now to also do some requests from my C# .NET Core 3.1. application, but no matter what I try, I do not get the same result. The API is not accepting my request as well.

```
        var fetchList = new FetchList();
        fetchList.fetch_list = "[{\"name\":\"itemInfo\",\"controller\":\"catalog.BLCCatalogItem\",\"method\":\"getDetailWithColor\",\"params\":[264,86]}]";
        string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fetchList);

        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 128;
        aes.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor();

        byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);

        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(dest.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in dest)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        var output =  hex.ToString();
```

And FetchList Class:

```
public class FetchList
{
    public string fetch_list { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [`createCipher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatecipheralgorithm-password-options) interprets the 2nd argument as a passphrase and derives the key from it. The method is deprecated and should be replaced by [`createCipheriv()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatecipherivalgorithm-key-iv-options). The key must be hex decoded to be 16 bytes in size and compatible with AES-128-ECB. Note that ECB is an insecure mode.

Comment: As I pointed out the problem is on the C# part, JavaScript is working fine so far (except of the deprecated createCipher(). Thanks for this, will check this out). The API is an external one, so ECB is not chosen from me.

Comment: If you want to keep `createCipher()` you have to derive the key in the C# code with `EVP_BytesToKey()`. There are implementations for C# on the internet. I would advise against this, `EVP_BytesToKey()` is insecure and deprecated (that is why `createCipher()` is deprecated). Better switch to `createCipheriv()`. Regarding the C# code: The C# code also seems to be missing the hex decoding of the key. Are you sure that the Utf8 encoding of `message` is identical in both codes? Couldn't verify because I couldn't find `FetchList`.

Comment: Thanks, will try it with `EVP_BytesToKey()`. FetchList is just a simple class with a single property of type string to get the same object as it is in JavaScript. I added it on the initial post. The message contains nothing that needs to be secured in first place, so I guess the idea behind it to encrypt the request body was something else.

Comment: A possible implementation of `EVP_BytesToKey()` can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/caspencer/1339719). `createCipher()` uses no salt, as digest MD5 and an iteration count of 1 (there are also leaner implementations on the web that already take into account the missing salt and the iteration count of 1). If you interpret `E572F45E8D79CAF92B4BD3B375820831` as passphrase, from a technical point of view no hex decoding for AES-128 is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Topaco I was able to solf my problem. here is how the code now looks like:

```
        var key = new OpenSslCompatDeriveBytes(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("E572F45E8D79CAF92B4BD3B375820831"), null, "MD5", 1).GetBytes(16);

        var fetchList = new FetchList();
        fetchList.fetch_list = "[{\"name\":\"itemInfo\",\"controller\":\"catalog.BLCCatalogItem\",\"method\":\"getDetailWithColor\",\"params\":[137696,115]}]";
        string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fetchList);

        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 128;
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor();

        byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);

        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(dest.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in dest)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        var output =  hex.ToString();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).